# java utf8 encoding outputstream not working

Tags: java, encoding, outputstream

I need to write a program which is able to write UTF-8 data into a file.

I found out examples on the internet, however, I am not able to progress to desired result.

Code:

```
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.Writer;

public class UTF8WriterDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Writer out = null;
        try {
            out = new BufferedWriter(
                    new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream("c://java//temp.txt"), "UTF-8"));


            String text = "This texáát will be added to File !!";

            out.write(text);
            out.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

Everything run succesfully, but at the end I see special characters not showing properly: 
This texÃ¡Ã¡t will be added to File !!

I tried several examples from the internet with the same result.

I use Visual Studio code.

Where could be the problem please?

Thank you

Comment: Do you use Visual Studio Code for your Java file, or do you use it to view your `temp.txt`, or both?

Comment: only for java file

Comment: There lies the problem: your source code file is not encoded as UTF-8. You should grab a decent IDE or text editor and set the file's charset to UTF-8.

Comment: oh, I like VS Code :( Probably there will be an option how to encode source code file in UTF-8, no?

Comment: even there is in the bottom right pane the possibility to change encoding in VS code, but obiously it doesn`t help

Comment: With which application are you *viewing* the file?

Comment: I think VS Code is not the problem. I tried to run java code only through cmd, and still the encoding problem. Application I tried to save as txt and csv, to open the file I used notepad, sublime and excel. Each try with the same incorrect result.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187509/discussion-between-mc-emperor-and-bennes).

Answer (score 2):

Your code is correct. You probably already have a file named *temp.txt*, and therefore Java writes text to the existing file (replacing previous content). What can be a problem is an encoding, that you already have set in your file.

In other words, you can't (or at least shouldn't) write UTF-8 text to the file with for example WINDOWS-1250 encoding or you would get an exact result as you have described.

If you didn't have this file, Java would automatically create a file with UTF-8 encoding.

**Possible solutions:**

1. Change encoding of your current file (usually you can open it in any text editor, use *Save as* and then specify encoding as *UTF-8*.
2. Remove this file and Java will create it automatically with proper encoding.

---

By the way, you should use `StandardCharsets` class instead of using `String charsetName` in order to avoid UnsupportedEncodingException:

```
new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream("temp.txt"), StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
```

Comment: I would say you should use `StandardCharsets` rather than `String charsetName` to prevent a possible `UnsupportedEncodingException`.

Comment: This didn`t help. I got unmappable character problem, which was possible to solve defining system variable JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS with value: -Dfile.encoding=UTF8. Like this I am able to see special characters.

Comment: hm but only within cmd its working. Running in VS Code provides the data with the same problem for csv file, for txt it`s working. So probably some setting in excel.

Answer (score 0):

When you say "I see special characters not showing properly", where are you seeing them?

What you say/show next *looks* like the string, utf-8 encoded (i.e. the accented a's are each represented by 2 chars, in what appears to be the appropriate encoding).

What I would expect the issue to be is that the java code is not outputting a BOM at the beginning of the file, leaving the interpretation of utf-8 sequences up to the discretion of the reader.